# How to create a distribution archive (zip) containing project jars and war in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to create a Zip task that would create a distribution package for my project that contains project jar files and war (and potentially other build artifacts produced by the `assemble` task).

So I tried writing this simple script

```
task dist(dependsOn: 'assemble', type: Zip){
  into('lib'){
    from 'build/libs' //contains jar and war files
  }
  ... //other stuff
}
```

Task `dist` depends on `assemble` because it conveniently includes the tasks that create jar and war files.

But if I try to execute that, gradle complains with this error message:

```
Circular dependency between tasks. Cycle includes [task ':assemble', task ':dist'].
```

I've checked out the [specification for `assemble` task](http://gradle.org/releases/0.9.2/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#N11758), and it is clearly written that `assemble` task automatically `dependsOn` all archive tasks in the project, which obviously includes my `dist` task. And there seems to be no way to get around it.

What would be the *correct* way of doing this in gradle? How can I make a zip task that depends on `assemble` task? I could make `dist` task explicitly depend on `jar` and `war` tasks, but I think that kind of violates encapsulation a bit.

I am using gradle-1.0-milestone-3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is a complete example to depend your Zip on the jar and the war task:

```
task dist(type:Zip){
    from jar.outputs.files
    from war.outputs.files
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good, but wouldn't it also include the contents of all Jar tasks in my zip? (I'll try it out later when I get home). Originally what I wanted was to make a distribution package which contains outputs of `jar` and `war` tasks *only*. Your solution should do the trick for now, but if I were to add some auxiliary jar tasks later looks like they might end up in my zip.

Comment: sorry, I thought you mean all tasks of type Jar and War. I refactored the sample above to fit your needs. I hope we get closer to a suitable solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get all created archives of a build into your dist zip:

```
task dist(type:Zip){
    tasks.withType(AbstractArchiveTask).each{ archiveTask ->
        if(archiveTask!=dist){
            from archiveTask.outputs.files
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but pretty verbose. Also it would break if I had another similar `dist2` task.

Comment: could you explain what would break with a second dist2 task? the if clause is just needed to avoid a loop.

Comment: I meant that if I were to have another distribution task (`dist2`) its output files would be included in `dist`, whereas I just want the output of `assemble` (i.e. `jar` and `war`). In fact, the contents of `archiveTask.outputs.files` is not that important to me. I just want to make sure that `jar` and `war` tasks are executed before `dist` task.

Comment: in with case you should use the example above with `tasks.withType(Jar)` as War inherits from Jar.